# Haskell- Funcion que devuleve Maybe

Tags: lista, programación-funcional, haskell

estoy haciendo esta función find, si la uso con "[a] -> Int", funciona correctamente, pero yo necesito que me devuelva el resultado envuelto en un Maybe, no logro modificar los parámetros para que me funcione. Si alguien me pude dar una mano , lo agradezco..

```
find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
find x = length.(filter x)
```

Comment: Sugerencia: la función debería devolver `Just` el primer elemento de la lista que responde al predicado, o `Nothing` si no existe tal elemento.

Comment: Claro, la función debería devolver just o nothing, el tema es que no estoy logrando desarrollar la función con Maybe

Comment: ¿Cómo diseñarías la función sin `Maybe`? Empieza con `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> a`.

Comment: find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int   --------Asi Y de esta manera funciona, me devulve un entero, pero tengo que hacerlo con Maybe x eso consulto

Comment: `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int` Pero esto no es lo que debes hacer en absoluto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función, tal como la defines, es incorrecta. `length` devuelve un `Int`, por lo que forzarías que fuese una lista se de enteros: `find :: (Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> Int`

Por la *signatura* de la función entiendo que lo que pretendes es localizar el primer elemento que cumplan un *predicado*. Algo que se podría definir así:

```hs
find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> a
find pred (x:xs) | pred x = x
                 | otherwise = find pred xs
```

Para el caso de que la lista no contenga ningún elemento que cumpla el predicado o que esté vacía, podemos añadirlo usando el tipo `Maybe`:

```hs
find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
find _ [] = Nothing
find pred (x:xs) | pred x = Just x
                 | otherwise = find pred xs
```

La *recursividad* es fundamental en programación funcional. Pero si no se quiere usar en este caso, se podría definir de este modo:

```hs
find :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Maybe a
find pred = first . filter pred
  where first [] = Nothing
        first (x:_) = Just x
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Chema, me fue de gran ayuda...